# How can i change the state of thread which is getting accessed in another monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am implementing a controller class, which has to apply lock on a thread which will process same kind of data. So in this scenario i have built two classes for apllying and releasing locks.

Now I am getting IllegalMonitorStateException exception, at time of realsing lock.
I know currently i am in another thread's monitor.

This is Locking mechanism:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread> Map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread>();
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    final Object lock = new Object();
    for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(thread.getName().toString());
        if ((sb.length() == 22) && (sb.toString().matches("[0-9]+"))
                && (thread != Thread.currentThread())) {
            utiMap.put(thread.getName().toString(), thread);
        }
    }

    synchronized (lock) {
        if (utiMap.containsKey(key)) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Following is the lock relase logic.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread> Map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread>();
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Object lock = new Object();
    for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(thread.getName().toString());
        if ((sb.length() == 22) && (sb.toString().matches("[0-9]+"))
                && (thread != Thread.currentThread()) && thread.getState().name().equals("WAITING")) {
            utiMap.put(thread.getName().toString(), thread);
            System.out.println("I am in controller Release -- ");
            thread.resume();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any locking going on. The object on which is locked is only created and used nowhere. Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: Don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: I suggest to take a look to the synchronization tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: I am adding locking mechanism as well.

Comment: You have a lot of redundant code which doesn't do anything.  I suggest you simplify your code and it will be clearer as to what it is really doing. e.g. you don't need to `toString()` a String and copy it into a buffer and toString() that.  matches is pretty slow..  You don't have to keep called Thread.currentThread() you can compare enum values not their String name.

Comment: @BITSSANDESH So show us the code which is having a problem, not the code which works.  BTW resume() is deprecated and should only be used on suspend()ed thread which you shouldn't use either.

Comment: Till now this is so naive code, becuase this is in testing phase, i'll change as code will be finalyze.

Comment: Locking a local object doesn't do anything as there is no other thread which has access to it.  When you use notify/notifyAll you should modify the state of a field and you should check this which you wait() otherwise you get unpredictable results.

Comment: @Peter: The code under "Following is the lock relase logic." has problem in releasing lock on the waiting state thread. In this situation i am able to get thread, but unable to change thread's state.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve or why you would want to do this, but your code is has so many issues with it I am not sure this is something you should be attempting.  It is the sort of thing Oracle experts say you should not try and unless you really, really know what you are doing, it is likely to be a very bad idea.

Comment: @BITSSANDESH Correct, you can't change the state of a thread, you can only change the reason it is in that state. e.g. if it is blocking you can release the cause of the blocking, but only if you are that cause.  If you are blocking on IO you can close the connection to unblock it.

Comment: @Peter: I am getting illegalmonitor exception after using Thread.notify ,Thread.notifyall and same with Object.notify and Object.notifyall

Comment: This error means you are not the one holding the lock on that object.  You cannot use notify unless you are, nor would you want to.

Comment: Then how can i develop the singalling mechanism for communicating internally between the threads. Becuase i have c onstrait in design, I can't put controller class outside the object thread.

Comment: Ok, of the many signalling/messing/work passing methods in Java already and the many third party libraries which also do this, what would you say is the most similar and how do you need it to be different?

Comment: How about using Thread.interrupted() ??

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` will interrupt any interruptible operations. If the thread is not performing interruptible operations it will be the same as setting a flag which isn't being read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is ... I'm afraid ... totally wrong.

But worse than that, I suspect that you are trying to do something that cannot be done.  Or if it can be, then it shouldn't be done because it can't be done *safely*.

---

It seems that you are trying to have one thread cause another thread to stop running for a bit ... and then resume.  And you are trying to do this without the cooperation / participation of the controlled thread.  (That's the only interpretation I can think of for *"which has to apply lock on a thread"* ... and the gyrations that your code is performing.)

Unfortunately, you can't do that safely in Java.  If you were going to do this at all, you would need to call `thread.suspend()` on a thread object to temporary stop it, and then `thread.resume()` on the same thread object to let it continue.  But those two methods have been **deprecated** a long time ago because (apparently) they are dead-lock prone.

---

A couple of other things to note:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
...
synchronized(lock) { ....
```

That code is wrong.  Java primitive locks work by having multiple threads `synchronize` on one (shared) object.  But you are synchronizing on lock instances that one the current thread can see.  The net result will be that there is effectively no synchronization and no locking at all.

```
lock.wait();
```

This waits for some other thread to `notify` that `lock` object, but ...

- no other thread can see that `lock` object, and
- the only other place where `lock.notify` is called is on the current thread ... after you've woken up due to an interrupt.  (But if the thread is already woken up, the notify event will simply be discarded.)

---

Recommendations:

1. Don't try to pause / resume threads like that.  If you want a thread to be "controlled", then modify that thread to periodically check if it should pause.
2. You really, really need to read up on Java concurrency, 'cos your attempted solution is ... frankly ... rubbish.

Comment: it's look weird for me as well. Thasnk for nice explaination about my solution. I am figuring out the problem and I'll change the design.